# In SwiftUI how to access properties from UIViewRepresentable when calling updateUIView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to access properties such as `count` from a UIKit component within SwiftUI, the complier issue purple warnnings:

> Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

Although wrapping the state modification within `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` avoids the warning, it's acknowledged as a suboptimal solution. Directly exposing the uiView to SwiftUI for property access is another workaround, but it's also less than ideal.

So is there another way to do that?

Is there a more appropriate way to achieve this without resorting to these workarounds?

Please note, the example below is simplified to illustrate the problem. While I'm aware that `text.count` can be directly obtained in SwiftUI, there are scenarios where accessing such properties through UIKit components is necessary.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var count = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            UIKitTextField(text: $text, count: $count)
            Text("Word count: \(count)")
        }
    }
}
struct UIKitTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var count: Int
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        count = uiView.text?.count ?? 0
//        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
//            count = uiView.text?.count ?? 0
//        }
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: UIKitTextField
        init(_ textField: UIKitTextField) {
            self.parent = textField
        }
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update another example**

```swift
struct UIKitImageView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let asset: Asset?
    let hdrOpen: Bool
    @Binding var isImageHDR: Bool
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
        let view = UIImageView()
        update(view)
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: UIImageView, context: Context) {
        update(view)
    }
    func update(_ view: UIImageView) {
        if let url = asset?.file {
            view.image = ImageReader.image(contentsOf: url)
        } else if let data = asset?.data {
            view.image = ImageReader.image(data: data)
        } else {
            view.image = UIImage()
        }
        if hdrOpen {
            view.preferredImageDynamicRange = .high
        } else {
            view.preferredImageDynamicRange = .standard
        }
        isImageHDR = view.image!.isHighDynamicRange
    }
}
```

Comment: I see.  You can incorporate a closure into `View` and return a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a mistake in the representable implementation, make it like this:

```
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.textDidChange = nil
        uiView.text = text
        //count = uiView.text?.count ?? 0 make this a computed property in the parent View
        context.coordinator.textDidChange = { newText in
            text = newText
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator() // can't pass self because this is a struct not an object 
    }
```

And since text state is your source of truth you must access its length via a computed property any other way and it'll be inconsistent.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    var count: Int {
        text.count
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            UIKitTextField(text: $text)
            Text("Word count: \(count)")
        }
    }
}
```

Fixed code for second sample:

```
   let url: URL

   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
        let view = UIImageView()
        //update(view) updateUIView is already called after makeUIView so this is unnecessary
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: UIImageView, context: Context) {
        // need to check if url has changed
        if url != context.coordinator.url {
            update(view)
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. I have updated another code sample to show my question.

Comment: ok i have added the fix your second code sample